# Post link to Facebook including app URL scheme - iOS 6

Tags: ios, facebook, social-networking, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using the UIActivityViewController to share an image and url from within my app.
I'm having trouble formatting the facebook post. I attach an image using a subclassed `UIActivityItemProvider` and provide the text for the post in the same way.

I want to add a url, but it needs my apps custom url scheme in front of it like this
`myurl://image?url=http://imageurl.com`

The problem is, when this is posted, only the last half of the url is clickable (from http:// onwards). Which means it doesn't open my app with the url.

Is there another way to do this?
I know I can create an app on Facebook, but how can I tie the two together using the `UIActivityViewController`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options :

1. Create a simple server-side web service that will redirect from `http://yourserver.com/linkToApp/image` to `myurl://image` .
   It could even show a different page/preview if the app is not installed/if you're not on an ios device.
2. Create a facebook app and use "Deep linking" (it will basically do the same for you..)

Comment: Any help on deep linking? I created an app on facebook dev and entered app details. Whats needed to link the 2 together so a post from UIActivityView will show up on Facebook that it's from my app?

Comment: Do I need to use the Facebook SDK for deep linking, or can I still use the iOS built in Facebook posting?

Comment: @Darren you'll need the SDK for deep linking. +a facebook app.

Comment: I think that #1 will be much simpler : Just use simple redirect code

Comment: here's fb's tutorial for deep linking : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/link-to-your-native-app-ios-sdk/

Comment: Thanks. I'm just not sure how or even if I can use the FB SDK with the UIActivityViewController that presents the different sharing paths available.

Comment: I do actually have the url created by my own url shortener (Yourls.org) any tuts on how to do redirect depending on device etc..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33906/discussion-between-lou-weed-and-darren)

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I don't wanna build my own server, so it has to be solution #2. I followed the tutorials for deep link, but it doesn't actually say what is the link I'm supposed to share. Should it still be "myappurl://" ?